# joining two cylinder at extreme angle (15 degree)

Tags: topology

I am struggling joining these two cylinders in a clean way.

[image]

they are 3 main difficulties:

- the angle between the cylinders is really low.
- the area of meeting of the two cylinder is curved (it is not a straight line cylinder).
- the two cylinders have different diameter.

I have made multiples try but always end up with artifacts
[image]
[image]

The best result I get was by using a cylinder with a straight portion in the connecting area, but then even with the proportional editing on I didn't manage to curve that straight portion back in a good way:

[image]
[image]

I tried a simplified version (2 straight cylinder) but still ended with a bad shading[image]

[image]

Does anyone knows how to solve that ?

Here is the blend file if someone whant to give it a try:
[image]

Comment: could you please share your last attempt?

Comment: @moonboots sure, I re uploaded the blend file (with some explanation in it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 2 methods, **Boolean** or **cut a hole**:

In *Edit* mode you can create 2 x 8 vertex cylinders, rotate one 15°. Keep one selected and go into *Face > Intersect (Boolean)*:

[image]

Merge some vertices, use the knife to create horizontal edge loops, add some support edge loops:

[image]

Give it the Subdivision Surface modifier, move some vertices if you want it rounder:

[image]

You can also cut a hole, extrude inwards, then right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Stretch a bit:

[image]

Extrude, make circle again:

[image]

Deform the topology, etc:

[image]

Comment: yeah sure, but how to get get the curve I am looking for (as in the first picture of my question)?

Comment: I've edited with a second method